# EL&U Glossaries

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Would it be useful for us to have two EL&U Glossaries on the site.

The first could be for SE and EL&U specific abbreviations and acronyms, including ones that just happen to crop up a lot here.

The second could be for terminology that differs between different grammars, specialist fields and so forth.

So in one we could have *OP, FAQ, AFTK, TPTB, wiki* and so-forth. The other might have *apodosis*, *V3*, *NP*, *prep*, *predicator* and so on.

What do you think?

Comment: Fersher. We could start with easy ones like *tense* and *phrasal verb* and work our way up.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. Though I wouldn't be surprised if they turn out to be just as highly-adopted as the help center and tour are. :P

Comment: [We have the one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/147), but not the other,

Comment: Yes, users will find it useful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315968/what-does-ahd-mean

Comment: Yes, it would. But the real question is, would new users - the ones who seem to need it the most - really read it? Use it? Read it when it's pointed out to them? Care? Most people - not all, but most - simply want an answer; they don't want to wade through useful information before getting the answer they desire. This is the cynic in me talking.

Comment: @medica Well, yes. But I think the other real question is would they *find* it? I found it very difficult to navigate EL&U when I first got here. It might help if it was not a post on Meta, but a page on the main site, easily see-able. After all, a majority of the readers here aren't posters, they come here primarily to read. And most will never venture onto Meta at all.

Comment: Some sites (like health) have a permanent "box" (?) announcing something (on health, it's a disclaimer.) I can see something like this for quick help. Bit AFAIK, only CMs can approve and implement these, and the argument will be that that's what the help pages are for.

Comment: @medica What's AFAIK? CM=community mod?

Comment: Haha. AFAIK = As Far As I Know; CM = Community Manager (above the mods.) Reminds me of the TL;DR post. :)

Comment: One problem is that sometimes terminology *and* concepts differ, so you can't always map terms from one terminological universe to another :-(

Comment: @snailboat That's true. But we can try to do some mapping where we can though :) For example, V3=past participle or protasis= *if*-clause=antecedent.

Comment: It is unfortunate but FAQs, wikis, help are somehow hidden to new users (this is a universal principle about the web not just here). Also, to access by search, you need to use the site specific search and just the right keywords. But it would still be very welcome for you to create a grammar terminology FAQ/meta post, and to [add to our existing metapost of acronyms/abbrevs](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/147) (via @choster).

Comment: Don't forget that there are featured meta posts listed in the box on the right. The [featured] tag is set by moderators and could be applied to such questions.

Comment: +1. There's [precedent](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/list-of-common-abbreviations) for this idea on other SE sites.

Comment: Would the grammar-related terms support canonical Q&As on the main site?  Canonical main Q&As would be more discoverable than meta posts, would permit more detail (even multiple answers, for terms with multiple meanings), and can be used as duplicate closure targets.  (Disclaimer: my only ELU participation is flagging spam.)